# Django: Show 'copy file progress notifications' on GUI web page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I wanted to know if we can show 'progress notifications' on web GUI (template)? For example, I am copying contents of location X from my system(machine A) to location Y of another system(machine B). After that, I am executing a .exe file on the remote. So, I want to show the progress on my template as follows:

**Copying files and folders from location X to location Y on machine B...

Copy completed.

Executing xyz.exe on machine B...**

and so on.
I know there should be some way to do that, but am just not able to figure it out. It would help if someone can guide me in proper direction.
(An example to go along with this would be really helpful)

Comment: You will need to use some sort of AJAX to do that (i.e.:jQuery, Mojo).

Comment: I get you when you say using JQuery/Ajax. But my problem here is that the copy folder in done by a fuction that has various return codes. So, within a given folder, some files get copied and some files do not depending upon a logic. So, I want to show to the user which file is getting copied and which file is omitted. I am not sure how can I do that with JQuery?